# MATHCOUNTS NATIONAL 2014 #12

Tags: contest-math

I don't know how to approach this. The correct answer is $2013$.

> What is the value of
>
> $$\frac{2013^3-2\cdot 2013^2\cdot 2014+3\cdot 2013\cdot 2014^2-2014^3+1}{2013\cdot 2014}\,?$$

I thought about using Binomial Theorem in some way as the format looks similar to the results you get, but couldn't follow through with it.

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/294354)

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/72031) is a mathjax tutorial written for beginners. Please go through the same and try to typset your question using mathjax instead of links to external source. Also it would be great if you can provide your own ideas for solving this problem.

Comment: Thank you to whoever reformatted the question for me.

Comment: You can try to identify the expression with  typical formula from school algebra. Can you do that?

Comment: What do you mean by the "typical formula"?

Comment: Have you studied formulas for $(a+b) ^2,(a-b)^2,(a+b)^3,(a-b)^3$ in your school? Try to replace 2013 by $a$ and $2014$ by $b$ and see if you can find any formula similar to the expression in question.

Comment: You should also note that we don't need binomial theorem here. The binomial theorem extends such formula for larger powers.

Comment: I see no legitimate grounds for closing the question: the OP did in fact provide context (the tag) and evidence of having thought about the question and made a relevant observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of using the binomial theorem is a good one, but there’s a little more work to be done. Most of the numerator looks a lot like the result of expanding $(2013-2014)^3$, so you should start by writing out that expansion. Then you can easily see that the numerator is

$$(2013-2014)^3+2013^2\cdot 2014+1\,;$$

Can you finish it from there?

Comment: Wow! Yes, I can. May I ask what you saw in order to realize that was the case?

Comment: @Smartsav10: I just looked at the expansion of $(2013-2014)^3$ and asked myself what adjustment needed to be made to get the numerator; and when I wrote that down, it all fell into place.

Comment: Thank you! I'll remember to start including expansions of things in my thought process.

Comment: @Smartsav10: You’re welcome!

Comment: I’d really like to know the justification for the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the expression $$\frac{a^3 - 2a^2b + 3ab^2 - b^3 + 1}{ab}$$ where $a = 2013$ and $b = a+1 = 2014$

Put $b = a+1$ and simplify!

$$\frac{a^3 - 2a^2b + 3ab^2 - b^3 + 1}{ab} = \frac{a^2(a+1)}{a(a+1)} = a = 2013$$

Comment: While this works, I think for contest math it will be better to go with @Brian M. Scott’s  solution